# Nigeria Wards Shapefile

Tags: data-request, geospatial

Where can I find GIS Wards data for all of Nigeria?

I tried searching everywhere to no avail.

Diva GIS only has the LGA layer, and I am looking for the level below that.

Answer (score 3):

OSM (OpenStreetMap) have all their map data in [this server](http://download.geofabrik.de/). You can download all the data for Africa inside the ".osm.pdf" column.
This is a file with all the data that OSM have about Africa. However, it is a very heavy file and it is hard to work with.
If you click  on "Africa" you will have a list of all the countries including [Nigeria](http://download.geofabrik.de/africa.html).

Once you have the file you can open it as a vector layer and this window will open:

[image]

My recommendation is to open each layer separately so will be able you look into it and adjust the settings.

Answer (score 3):

**Administrative Levels:**
Nigerian administrative boundaries are broken in states, senatorial districts, Local Government Areas (LGAs) and Wards. As at the time of writing this, there are *36 states (and federal capital territory, Abuja), 109 senatorial districts, 775 LGAs and 8809 Wards*.

So, in other words the country is broken into states, the states are broken into LAGs (in some cases, [senatorial districts](https://umar-yusuf.blogspot.com/2017/10/map-of-nigeria-senatorial-districts-by.html)) and the LGAs are further broken in Wards as seen below.

**The Maps:**

**1) International Boundary**
[image]

**2) States Boundary**
[image]

**3) LGAs Boundary**
[image]

**4) Senatorial Districts Boundary ([get them here](https://umar-yusuf.blogspot.com/2017/10/map-of-nigeria-senatorial-districts-by.html))**

**5) Wards Boundary**
[image]

**Who defines which boundary:**
The state boundaries are maintained by the central/federal government, the senatorial districts and LGA boundaries are maintained by the states (note that a state is sub-divided into three senatorial district and each district is made up of at least three/more LGAs in most cases). While the wards boundaries are defined and maintained by LGAs.

While states and LGA boundaries are documented in form of maps, not much attention is given to documenting wards boundary in the form of map.

However, organizations such as Independent National Electoral Commission, National Population Commission, National Bureau of Statistics, National Identity Management Commission, National Agency for Food and Drug Administration and Control, Nigerian Electricity Regulatory Commission etc often do project that involves dealing with wards level boundaries and over the years, they have numerous collections of data that when put together under a central body can be used to maintain ward boundary map.

This is a gap, that exist for long in which my organization has recently filled out. Today, you can [download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jYzwKvTsVaJe5Z3Rb0zpALC7HWmtngDk/view?usp=sharing) the ward level image map as seen above from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jYzwKvTsVaJe5Z3Rb0zpALC7HWmtngDk/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 2):

I've been unable to find any shapefiles of wards for all of Nigeria (I'd love to know where userPyGeo accessed his data), but I have found two downloadable shapefiles for north and northeast Nigeria, here: https://geonode.wfp.org/layers/geonode%3Anga_bnd_adm3wards_062015 and here: https://data.humdata.org/dataset/nga-administrative-boundaries, respectively. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

check this link. I was thankful I found it

https://data.grid3.org/datasets/0824aded5f5a4d39b10871c667aa8ccf_139/explore?location=9.046621%2C8.685290%2C7.09